# Find last 12 month + current month sale (my date format is string in mysql)

Tags: mysql, inner-join

```
SELECT pd.DC_Date, SUM(pd.Quantity-pd.Credit_Quantity) AS 'Sales' 
FROM past_year_data PD
INNER JOIN idash_tb2_product_list PL ON PD.Product_Name = PL.Product_Name
WHERE PD.Branch_Name = 'Delhi'
AND DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(DC_Date,'%m'), '%M') = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('7/31/2017', '%m'), '%M')
```

This is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Please provide more information: table structure, example data and the output you have and the output you want to have.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `String` to `Date` and compare using `BETWEEN` and `DATE_ADD` function, e.g.:

```
SELECT pd.DC_Date,sum(pd.Quantity-pd.Credit_Quantity) AS 'Sales' 
FROM past_year_data pd
JOIN idash_tb2_product_list PL ON PD.Product_Name=PL.Product_Name
WHERE pd.Branch_Name = 'Delhi' AND
STR_TO_DATE(DC_Date,'%m') BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -12 MONTH) AND NOW();
```

Comment: I want last 12 month + current month

Comment: @TanviBansal this would cover both (current month and last 12 months) as we are using `NOW()`.

Comment: now() function is not working because i have data till date yesterday i.e 7/31/2017

Comment: It does not really matter as we are querying for a date range anyway (using `BETWEEN`). It will return all the data between today's date and last year's date regardless of what's the latest date.

Comment: Can you add the table structure and expected output?

Comment: My expected output is june -16 to july -17 (all months) and table structure for date is varchar and format is string

Comment: @TanviBansal Okay, if you want the output from June-16 to July-17 then we need to change the condition to `STR_TO_DATE(DC_Date,'%m') BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -12 MONTH) AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)`